# Simple onclick event not performing as excpected

Tags: javascript, html

I have an onclick event with two buttons. Button 1 should make the product cycle backward, to the previous item. Button 2 should do the opposite. However, they are not doing what the should be.

HTML:

```js
 'use strict';
    
    var minProduct = 1;
    var maxProduct = 3;
    var currentProduct = 1;
    
    var products = [
        {
            'title': 'Test Title',
            'desc': 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.'
        },
        {
            'title': 'Test Title2',
            'desc': '2Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.'
        },
        {
            'title': 'Test Title3',
            'desc': '3Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.'
        },
    ];
    
    function updateText(productNumber) {
        var obj = products[productNumber-1];
        var title = document.getElementById("title");
        var desc = document.getElementById("desc");
        title.innerHTML = obj.title;
        desc.innerHTML = obj.desc;
    };
    
    
    document.getElementById('back').onclick = function() {
        console.log('back');
        if (!currentProduct == minProduct){
            currentProduct = currentProduct--;
            updateText(currentProduct);
        };
    };
    
    document.getElementById('forward').onlick = function() {
        if (!currentProduct == maxProduct){
            currentProduct = currentProduct++;
            updateText(currentProduct);
        };
    };
```

```html
<div class="nav clearfix">
    <img src="./logo.png" class="nav-title" alt="Daicicle's Combos" width="105x">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<h1 class="title">Store.</h1>


<div class="product">
    <h2 class="product-title" id="title">Test Title</h2>
    <p class="product-desc" id="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.</p>
    <ul class="product-btn-ul">
        <li><button class="product-btnz btn-go" id="back">&lt;</button></li>
        <li>
            <button class="product-btn purchase">Buy</button>
        </li>
        <li><button class="product-btnz btn-go" id="forward">&gt;</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not sure if you need CSS, if so comment and ill add.

The console is empty of errors.
The onclicks are properly tested.

Comment: In your forward event click handler you have a typo error you spelled it as `onlick` instead of `onclick` I don't know if that was intentional or not.

Comment: Instead of `currentProduct = currentProduct++` you should just write `currentProduct++;` Same for `currentProduct--`

Comment: Instead of `if (!currentProduct == minProduct)` You are looking for `if (currentProduct !== minProduct)`

Comment: With all the 3 above comment's suggestions applied, your code works :)

Comment: I am not completely sure how to fix this, but I noticed you have a typo: you did onlick not onclick Hopefully that's all it was! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved w/ help of comments. Solution:

- spelled it as `onlick` instead of `onclick`
- Instead of `currentProduct = currentProduct++` you should just write `currentProduct++;`Same for `currentProduct--`
- `if (!currentProduct == minProduct)` You are looking for `if (currentProduct !== minProduct)`

Commenters:

- LGSon
- chevybow
- soktinpk
- Jorden

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Daicicle's Combos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="./favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      'use strict';

var minProduct = 1;
var maxProduct = 3;
var currentProduct = 1;
var products = [
    {
        'title': 'Test Title',
        'desc': 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.'
    },
    {
        'title': 'Test Title2',
        'desc': '2Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.'
    },
    {
        'title': 'Test Title3',
        'desc': '3Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Excepturi, necessitatibus nihil animi possimus quisquam laudantium sunt corporis nulla soluta nam.'
    },
];

function updateText(productNumber) {
  console.log('product #' + productNumber);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(products[productNumber-1]));
    var obj = products[productNumber-1];
    var title = document.getElementById("title");
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc");
    title.innerHTML = obj.title;
    desc.innerHTML = obj.desc;
};



updateText(currentProduct);
document.getElementById('back').onclick = function() {
    if (currentProduct !== minProduct){
        currentProduct--;
        updateText(currentProduct);
    };
};

document.getElementById('forward').onclick = function() {
  console.log('forward');
    if (currentProduct !== maxProduct){
        currentProduct++;
        updateText(currentProduct);
    };
};
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav clearfix">
        <img src="./logo.png" class="nav-title" alt="Daicicle's Combos" width="105x">
        <nav>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title">Store..</h1>


    <div class="product">
        <h2 class="product-title" id="title">Test Title</h2>
        <p class="product-desc" id="desc"></p>
        <ul class="product-btn-ul">
            <li><button class="product-btnz btn-go" id="back">&lt;</button></li>
            <li>
                <button class="product-btn purchase">Buy</button>
            </li>
            <li><button class="product-btnz btn-go" id="forward">&gt;</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./product.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And code pen here --> https://codepen.io/masankar/pen/VEvLgv